# Create bash log file for measuring runtime of c++ program

Tags: c++, bash, time, timestamp

I have two slightly different C++ programs and want to compare their runtime profiles. 
How is it possible to start both simultaneously, track the overall execution time and also store the timestamps of every console output into a log file?

For tracking the overall execution I just used the bash `time` command. But I cannot figure out how to print a timestamp in front of every `cout` on the console.

Any tipps/ hints are appreciated!

Comment: `./prog | while read x; do date +%H:%M:%S; echo $x; done`

Comment: [`./prog | ts`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1ssl/ts/)